# Расширение для Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql

Добрый день. Коллеги, у меня утилитарный вопрос - по работе часто приходится иметь дело с SQL-запросами, записанными в виде строк внутри C#-кода примерно следующего вида:

```
const string query = @"SELECT someField
                       FROM SomeTable";
```

причем зачастую эти запросы бывают несколько более сложными, нежели тот, что приведен выше. Разумеется, подобный подход чреват ошибками, которые возникают  уже в рантайме если, скажем, в запросе была допущена синтаксическая ошибка. Собственно, вопрос: может, кто-то знает какое-нибудь расширение для Visual Studio, которое позволяет проверять синтаксис этих sql-запросов прямо в редакторе Visual Studio?

Comment: А тут погуглить вы явно не догадались. А всем ток эт и советуете. И за вас тут народ погуглил, постарался, как сложно! 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/6648526e-e1ca-4584-be3c-050478434635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно создавать запросы [вот так](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14b717xh.aspx) и проверять их [вот так](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x1d741dz.aspx).
Можно еще LINQ попробовать, если у вас там не сильно наворочено все.

Comment: речь к сожалению, не о создании, а о поддержке ста тысяч имеющихся запросов. LINQ тоже использовать не могу - переписывать проект, писавшийся несколько лет нет ни возможностей, ни времени

Comment: Тогда быть может подсветка синтаксиса SQL спасет вас:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3a662c6-28eb-4de9-9a29-d328b1ac3f6b?SRC=VSIDE

Либо с валидатором:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5cbb1881-7a82-46ae-887b-c1dbb8451666

Comment: спасибо, надеюсь, спасет)